# Are articles and sections mutually exclusive?

Tags: html

Would there ever be a case where something is both a section and an article at the same time?

For example, would this make sense?

```html
<section>
<article>
    some content
</article>
</section>
```

How about this?

```html
<article>
<section>
    some content
</section>
</article>
```

Also, this is tangentially related to the question but I often read that sections are like chapters. This means that sections usually have siblings. Then, would it ever make sense to have a singular section, or would you only have sections where there are two more more chapter-like things?

Edit: This question was marked as similar to the question "Difference between Section vs Article elements in HTML"

I already understand the differences between section and article. Articles are defined as "individual standalone pieces of content". Sections are often compared to chapters. I am wondering about content, if they exist, that falls under both the definition of articles and the definition of sections. What if tagging content as an article (and not a section) would ruin the chapter-like structure of sections? If I tagged the content as a section, it would imply the content is not an "individual standalone piece of content." This would not be a problem if articles and sections have no overlaps, but I am confused about content like a Twitter timeline, which could [fall under the overlap](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2022/07/article-section-elements-accessibility/#a-web-application-twitter). And if overlaps exist, why not tag the content as both an article and section like I have shown above?

Comment: You are not tagging content as both an article and a section in your examples. You have a section whose sole content is a single article in the first example and an article whose sole content is a single section in the second. You cannot combine tags like that. If there is an attribute (such as an ARIA `role`) that allows you to mark up an element as "also having the characteristics of" another, you can use that. You could also create a custom HTML element that combined the two, but most readers would not know what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Reading from W3 School's pages on [article](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_article.asp) and [section](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_section.asp) tags, you can understand that they serve distinct purposes and are valuable for screen readers, accessibility etc.

While the `article` tag is meant for forum posts, articles, news etc, and could potentially include an entire story, it could also be broken down into separate parts.

For example, an article about spaghetti carbonara can have an ingredients section, a preparation section, and cooking instructions all as different sections. The `section` tag could be used to contain these different sections like so:

```
<article>
    <h1>Spaghetti Carbonara</h1>

    <section>
        <h2>Ingredients</h2>
        Some ingredients...
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>Cooking Instructions</h2>
        Boil water etc...
    </section>
</article>
```

It is starting to become obvious that like most tags, the `article` and `section` tags have their individual uses. It is good practice to generally include a heading tag (`h1`, `h2` ...) in each section.

That said, it should be noted that the `section` tag is a little more generic, and should be used only when a more specific tag is not available to represent the desired element (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)).

Comment: This did not answer my question directly. Two things can serve different purposes and still overlap. For example, comedies and romances are two completely different genres, but a story can be both genres at the same time (it falls under the overlap of the two). Just like I can categorize a book as both a romance and a comedy, can I tag some content as both an article and a section?

Comment: @okop You certainly *could* wrap content in both tags but you'd be doing just that, wrapping. An article tag should generally be complete, in that it contains the entire content body. Remember that HTML tags usually don't provide actual functionality and their main purpose is to make up a structure or skeleton. In your example, it would make sense to write an article about any book inside `<article>` without the need to wrap that in a `<section>` as the article tag already distinguishes the content. If you want to categorize things, you can use actual meta-data on your webpage, such as #tags.